# Load/Reload specific plugin tab in typo3 add plugin page?

Tags: php, typo3

I have configured my extension to add an icon to quick select the plugin as WizIcon under the insert new record in page, and it works:
[image: My plugin WizIcon]

The only problem, is that once clicked, my plugin is selected, but with the first tab enabled by default:
[image: Autoselected Tab]

I want it to autoselect the "Plugin" tab, as it have the options for the plugin, as it is a pain clicking that tab everytime.
Is there a simple way to do that?

UPDATE: This also applies in flexforms with reload which will reload if field have changed, but will reload the first tab, rather than current one.

Any hint will be really apreciated. (No google info, no typo3 manual info nothing about this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is hardcoded to the TYPO3 source.

If you really want to change this you can take a look at "t3lib/class.t3lib_tceforms.php". There is a function **getDynTabMenu()** which returns a call to $GLOBALS['TBE_TEMPLATE']->getDynTabMenu(). The 7th parameter defines the default opened tab. This is set to 1. You might change this to any number. But be aware that this will change the default tab for any content element and it is really not recommended to patch the core locally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, a pitty I can't do nothing about it without side effects